# Проблемы с Gradle при сборке проекта

Tags: android, gradle

При сборке проекта получаю

```
Error:Cause: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1.2-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
            classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте 2.1.0 вместо 2.1.2

Comment: @Werder пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: В файле по пути gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.propierties какое значение выставлено у вас для атрибута "distributionUrl"?

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

поменял  на 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1.2-all.zip  и все равно ловлю ошибку

Comment: так я перешел по пути /Users/kirya46/.gradle/wrapper  и там папка dists gradle-2.1.0-all ,  gradle-2.1.1-all,  gradle-2.1.2-all  но там нету файла gradle-wrapper.propierties

Comment: Попробуйте вписать ```https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip``` в ```gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties```

Comment: @temq сработало,  можете опубликовать ответ, если можно с объяснением почему это сработало, а предыдущие варианты не сработали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании gradlewrapper'a для сборки проекта версия gradle задается в файле `gradle-wrapper.properties` через параметр `distributionUrl`.

Указав там  `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1.2-all.zip` вы определили версию `gradle` как `2.1.2`. Но такой версии скорей всего нет, поэтому и появлялось сообщение сообщающее о ошибки загрузки gradle такой версии. Наиболее актуальную версию можно найти на сайте [gradle.org](https://gradle.org/)